# How to write piecewise function in jupyter notebook markdown?

Tags: python-3.x, latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tex

I'm trying to write a piecewise function in markdown on jupyter and jupyter is being spooky. Out of three functions, it only displays one properly (the $n_o$ one), even though they are all written in the same manner.

Is there a more elegant way to write this up?

```
$$ N(a)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      n_o & A>A_{krit} \\
      n_o+2 & A=A_{krit} \\
      n_o+4 & A<A_{krit} \\
\end{array} 
\right, $$

gdje je: $$A=\frac{1}{|a|},$$ 

$$ A_{krit}(a)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{\sin(2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{\pi}{2})}{2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{\pi}{2}} & a>0 \\
      \frac{\sin(2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{3\pi}{2})}{2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{3\pi}{2}} & a<0\\
\end{array} 
\right, $$ i

$$ n_o(a)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      |floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})-1| & a>2\pi \\
      |floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})-1|-2 & 0<a<2\pi \land A\leq A_{krit} \\
      floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+1 & a<0 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$
```

Comment: That looks more like latex then python - why the python flag?

Comment: @PatrickArtner because I'm using the jupyter environment to add some explanation to my code and can't willy-nilly import latex packages

Answer (score 10):

It seems there is spacing issue in your latex code. I just modified little bit, it works:

```
    $$ N(a)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      n_o & A>A_{krit} \\
      n_o+2 & A=A_{krit} \\
      n_o+4 & A<A_{krit} \\
\end{array} 
\right.  $$


gdje je: $$A=\frac{1}{|a|},$$ 

$$ A_{krit}(a)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{\sin(2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{\pi}{2})}{2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{\pi}{2}} & a>0 \\
      \frac{\sin(2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{3\pi}{2})}{2\pi*floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+\frac{3\pi}{2}} & a<0\\
\end{array} 
\right.  $$ i

$$ n_o(a)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      |floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})-1| & a>2\pi \\
      |floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})-1|-2 & 0<a<2\pi \land A\leq A_{krit} \\
      floor(\frac{|a|}{2*\pi})+1 & a<0 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$
```

[image: Sample Demo]